# 'code-server' showing blank page after login

Tags: linux, nginx

I am attempting to set up `code-server` on Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed `code-server` and can successfully log in, however as soon as I log in all I can see is a blank screen. Viewing the `nginx` error log shows the following.

Note that when navigating to the locations indicated in the error log from my browser, the objects load just fine. This leads me to believe that my `nginx` conf is somhow misconfigured.

```
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1956#1956: *60 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/code/browser/workbench/workbench.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/code/browser/workbench/workbench.js", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1955#1955: *50 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/loader.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/loader.js", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1956#1956: *57 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.js", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1956#1956: *55 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.nls.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.nls.js", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1956#1956: *54 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/webPackagePaths.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/webPackagePaths.js", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1956#1956: *49 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.css HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stable-2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/static/out/vs/workbench/workbench.web.main.css", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1956#1956: *49 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /_static/src/browser/media/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/_static/src/browser/media/favicon.ico", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
2023/09/12 09:26:28 [error] 1956#1956: *49 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: code.mydomain.com, request: "GET /_static/src/browser/media/favicon-dark-support.svg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/_static/src/browser/media/favicon-dark-support.svg", host: "code.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://code.mydomain.com/"
```

To install and configure both `code-server` and `nginx`, I followed the steps in [this guide](https://aws.plainenglish.io/how-to-run-an-instance-of-visual-studio-code-over-your-network-with-aws-ec2-d9fc6034c091).

Please also note that due to restrictions imposed by my business, I am unable to use `certbot` to generate an SSL certificate as described in the aforementioned guide, so I am simply running over HTTP. Perhaps this means that my `nginx` conf is now configured incorrectly?

Is anyone able to suggest what the issue may be and how I can resolve the issue?

#### `nginx` conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name code.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
    }
}
```